# Error al obtener datos de un Spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy obteniendo unos datos de 3 spinner y me da error, dice que es un null object, sin embargo, este mismo código me funciona en otra activity, sólo que ahora lo estoy usando en un fragment y me da error.

Este es el logcat

```
05-03 23:14:29.952 32009-32009/com.example.matias.finalcode E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.matias.finalcode, PID: 32009
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.finalcode/com.example.matias.finalcode.InicioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.matias.finalcode.Fragments.InicioFragment_LookingService.onCreateView(InicioFragment_LookingService.java:161)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5995)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) 
05-03 23:14:29.954 788-6026/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.matias.finalcode/.InicioActivity
```

Y este es el código de mis spinner y de las variables donde obtengo los datos del spinner

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio_lookingservice, container, false);

    signOut = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.sign_out); //--------ESTO ES PARA LOGOUT
    email = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnseleccionar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnseleccionar);
    spinnerPro = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProvincia);
    spinnerLoc = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocalizacion);
    spinnerTipoEmpresa = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoEmpresa);
    spinnerElegirEmpresa = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerElegirEmpresa);
    email.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    // ESTO ES PARA LOS SPINNER

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(),
            R.array.array_provincias,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPro.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerPro.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinnerLoc.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // Tu código aquí

            final String selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //txtloc.setText(selecteditem);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // Tu código aquí
        }

    });

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterempresa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(),
            R.array.array_tipoempresa,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerTipoEmpresa.setAdapter(adapterempresa);
    spinnerTipoEmpresa.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final String selecteditemEmp = spinnerTipoEmpresa.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    final String selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String selecteditemEmp = spinnerTipoEmpresa.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String provincias = provincia;

    mDatabase.child("z Empresas " + provincia).child(selecteditemLoc).child(selecteditemEmp).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Is better to use a List, because you don't know the size
            // of the iterator returned by dataSnapshot.getChildren() to
            // initialize the array
            final List<String> Usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot usuarioSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String Usuario = usuarioSnapshot.child("Usuario").getValue(String.class);
                Usuarios.add(Usuario);
            }

            spinnerElegirEmpresa = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerElegirEmpresa);
            ArrayAdapter<String> empresasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Usuarios);
            empresasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerElegirEmpresa.setAdapter(empresasAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // ESTO ES PARA LOS SPINNER

    return vista;
}

// ESTO ES PARA LOS SPINNER FUERA DEL ONCREATEVIEW
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    int[] localidades = {R.array.array_selecciona, R.array.array_sevilla, R.array.array_malaga};

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(),
            localidades[i],
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLoc.setAdapter(adapter);

    //txtloc.setText(spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString());
    //txtpro.setText(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
    provincia = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
// ESTO ES PARA LOS SPINNER
```

Y estos son los array de los que obtengo los valores para los spinner, se encuentran en el archivo string.xml

```
<string-array name="array_tipoempresa">
        <item>Selecciona un tipo de empresa</item>
        <item>Banco</item>
        <item>Farmacia</item>
        <item>Notaría</item>
        <item>Ferretería</item>
        <item>Atención pública</item>
        <item>Hospital</item>
        <item>Telefonía</item>
        <item>Otro tipo de empresas</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_selecciona">
        <item>Selecciona una ciudad</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_provincias">
        <item>Selecciona un país</item>
        <item>Sevilla</item>
        <item>Malaga</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_sevilla">
        <item>Selecciona una ciudad</item>
        <item>Tomares</item>
        <item>Camas</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_malaga">
        <item>Selecciona una ciudad</item>
        <item>Casares</item>
        <item>Estepona</item>
    </string-array>
```

Cuál será el problema por el que me dice que es un null object reference, si este mismo código me funciona en una activity normal y ahora en un fragment me da error...

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Parece un problema de acceso a la vista del Fragment, coloca el código donde los referencias

Comment: El problema es que `getSelectedItem()` en alguna parte te devuelve `null` y ese null le estas convirtiendo a `String`. ¿Eso te sucede al clickar o al momento de crear la vista del `Fragment`?. ¿Cual es el codigo que esta en la `linea 161` de tu `Fragment` en el `onCreateView`?

Comment: @Andrespengineer la linea 161 es la variable 1, la que dice final String selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: En efecto, estas seteando la data a spinnerLoc al final en un onItemSelected y estas intentando obtener el item antes de que tenga esa data. Arriba solo seas la data de `spinnerPro` y `spinnerTipoEmpresa`, ¿de casualidad te habrás confundido al intentar obtener el item de `spinnerLoc` y no de `spinnerPro`  que es quien si esta definido arriba?, si quieres la data de `spinnerLoc` debes hacerlo despues del setAdapter en el `onItemClick` que esta fuera del `onCreateView`

Comment: @Andrespengineer lo que pasa es que spinnerPro y spinnerLoc están conectados, es necesario primero elegir un dato de spinnerPro para que después me muestre las opciones de spinnerLoc dependiendo de lo que haya escogido. Es por esto que no se como subirlo, ya que los OnSelectedItem del spinnerPro se encuentran fuera del OnCreateView...

Comment: Yo creo que también el problema se debe a que las variables que genero dentro de los OnSelectedItem no las puedo usar afuera, no las reconoce. En la Acitivity normal no tengo ese problema y puedo usar esas mismas variables fuera y obtienen el mismo valor que tengo dentro del OnSelectedItem, pero aquí en el fragment me aparecen en rojo las variables cuando las uso afuera de ese código... No sé si se entiende.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas si, ese es el problema. declaralas global, mira la actualizacion del codigo que hice. Dejame saber como te va.

Comment: @Andrespengineer gracias amigo, con eso se me solucionó el problema. Eres un genio, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dice la excepción, el error ocurre en la siguiente linea:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                     at
>   com.example.matias.finalcode.Fragments.InicioFragment_LookingService.onCreateView(InicioFragment_LookingService.java:**161**)

Suponiendo que se refiere a esto:

```
final String selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
final String selecteditemEmp = spinnerTipoEmpresa.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Debes asegurarte que dichos `Spinners`, tanto `spinnerLoc`, como `spinnerTipoEmpresa` tengan un ítem seleccionado a la hora de invocar `getSelectedItem()`, ya que si no es asi, este te devuelve `null` y a dicho `null` le estas haciendo una conversion a `toString();`. Si estas obteniendo los datos que se van a cargar a los Spinners de manera asincrona, es decir que la data tarda un poco en llegar, deberias asignar dichos valores a sus variables, dentro del listener que obtiene la data, una vez hecho el set de los valores al `Spinner`. De todas formas no esta demas chequear si el dato no es nulo antes de guardarlo en una variable, con un simple if, ejemplo:

```
if(spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem() != null)
   selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Si no es el caso anterior descrito, tienes otra opción:

- Asignar el `onItemSelectedListener` antes de asignar o seleccionar el elemento que quieres como seleccionado manualmente.
- Asignar el elemento manualmente del ítem que quieres ejemplo: `spinnerLoc.setSelection(/*indice del elemento*/);`
- Una vez hecho los dos pasos anteriores, asignar el valor en el `onItemSelected` correspondiente al `Spinner`.

  ```
  selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
  ```

**Actualizacion:**

Según me cuentas en tu comentario, lo que quieres es "obtener los datos pero teniendo en cuenta que los `Spinners` estan conectados":

Simplemente haz lo siguiente:

Elimina todas las variables locales:

```
final String selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
final String selecteditemEmp = spinnerTipoEmpresa.getSelectedItem().toString();
final provincia = provincias;
```

Declara las variables que guardaran los datos del item seleccionado de manera global, en la clase.

```
private String selecteditemLoc;
private String selecteditemEmp;
private String provincia;
```

y en cada `onItemSelected` llamar su valor correspondiente, por ejemplo para `spinnerLoc`:

```
spinnerLoc.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            selecteditemLoc = spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // Tu código aquí
        }
    });
```

y así con cada uno de los valores. Asi te aseguras que en dichas variables, se guardaran sus respectivos valores seleccionados y puedes utilizarlas en cualquier parte de la clase.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esos valores los estoy leyendo desde un archivo string.xml y este mismo código no me da error en una activity normal, me esta dando error en el fragment...

Comment: arriba cambie el código y lo puse completo para que veas el oncreateview y los array desde donde estoy obteniendo los valores de mis spinner. Gracias por tu tiempo!